# How to avoid creating the same window in wxPython?

Tags: python-3.x, window, wxpython

I am creating an application that will have several windows. However, most of the windows should be created only one time. If window B already exists then instead of creating a new window B, the existing window B should be shown. It may be that window B was created but then destroyed and then, of course, I have to create window B again.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to know if windows B exists.

In the example below from the "Initial Window" you can create as many secondary windows as you want. I need a way to make sure that only one secondary window exists at a given time.

I am using Phython3.7 and wxPython 4.0.3

```
import wx


class FrameA(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        super().__init__(parent, title=title)

        self.i = 1

        self.panel   = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer   = wx.GridBagSizer(1, 1)

        self.buttonUtil = wx.Button(self.panel, label='New Window')

        self.sizer.Add(self.buttonUtil, pos=(0, 0))

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer) 

        self.buttonUtil.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Util)

        self.Centre()

    def Util(self, event):

        frame = FrameB(None, title=str(self.i))
        frame.Show()
        self.i += 1

class FrameB(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        super().__init__(parent, title=title)


app = wx.App()
frameA = FrameA(None, title='Initial Window')
frameA.Show()
app.SetTopWindow(frameA)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store created `FrameB` in an object variable in `FrameA`, e.g. as `self.frame`. In `FrameA` constructor initialize this variable to `None`.

In constructor of `FrameB` add parameter to store the creating `FrameA` (if multiple can exist). Then bind to close event to set `frame` of creating `FrameA` to `None` if B is closed.

In `Util()` check first if `frame` is `None`. If so, create new `FrameB` and assign it to `self.frame`. Otherwise focus existing B.

Comment: So, there is no built-in mechanism in wxPython to keep track of windows/frames?

Comment: @kbr85 There is [`wx.GetTopLevelWindows()`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.functions.html#wx.GetTopLevelWindows)

Comment: @kbr85 its trivial to track it for yourself, there's no need for wxPython to do it for you